# DDNS from ISP, accessable from outside, but not inside

Tags: networking, dns, routes, subdomain, dhcp

So, I recently found out that my ISP has this free feature, so I decided that I want to build a small server back home, to run a few stuff as a FTP, HTTP, SSH, few databases, you got the idea.

Maybe I should start by shortly describing my local network. I have a router and a main PC, the PC will run all the servers.
I configured DHCP to keep `192.168.0.2` for main PC's MAC address, and created a virtual server (Forwarding -> Virtual servers -> Add new) that maps port 80 to 80 on `192.168.0.2`, both TCP and UDP. I'm also running apache2, on ubuntu 16.04, and obviously can access localhost and see apache main page (on the main PC).

After many unnecessary reboots (I thought it will work!) I found out the from my laptop connected to the same router (lets say `192.168.0.3`) I cannot connect to my main PC by typing the external ip or the sudomain, **only** by the internal IP address `192.168.0.2`. If I connect to another network with my laptop (hotspot) and try to access the subdomain, it works.

I want to be able to access my subdomain from inside my local network, but apparently I can't, only from the outside.

Now I think that it's definitely from my router configuration, maybe I should set some kind of default gateway, to stop searching for the subdomain, because it's hosted right here. Anyone has a clue of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on how the router is configured (the NAT component).

Basically, the router has two (or more) IP addresses: the public one (let's say `128.66.1.1`) on the **WAN** port, and the private one (in this case, let's assume `192.168.0.1`) on the **LAN** port. Assuming a transmission to port 80 (HTTP) and correct port forwarding configuration, two scenarios are possible:

- *You're outside the network* (eg. in a café): any transmission (packet) will be routed to your home router by using the external IP address `128.66.1.1`. Then, when the packet arrives on the **WAN** port on your router, the *Port forwarding* (or *DMZ*) setting will re-route the packet to `192.168.0.2`. Everything is fine.
- *You're inside the network*: if you use the external IP address `128.66.1.1` (either by using it directly, or with any DNS name), the packet will be sent (by your PC) to the router **LAN** port in order to be routed to internet (your PC don't know that `192.168.0.2` is the final destination). If the router is configured to distinguish between packets sent to `128.66.1.1` and packets sent to `192.168.0.1`, then it will detect that the packet is meant to be routed to the external IP address assigned to **WAN**, and then it will use the same port forwarding settings as if the packet is entering from the **WAN** port. If it's not capable to distinguish between these two cases, you'll end up as the scenario that you're describing (in other words, the router will respond with its own resources, as if you contacted its internal IP).

Some routers can be configured from the UI, others requires a firmware modification (which can't be done by end users).

On `iptables`-based firewalls, this setting is controlled by the using of flags in rules of `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING` chains (`nat` table). Also, you need to configure a NAT rule (either `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE`) for packets that are coming from the internal network, with destination the external IP.